# IE not autosizing width of absolutely positioned element

Tags: css, internet-explorer, positioning, absolute, autosize

When I specify a `height` in the style for any element inside of this, IE makes the entire thing 100% width, rather than keeping it "autosized" for width.

Other browsers display it fine, but not IE.  How do I fix this?

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:50px;left:50px;background:green;">
 <div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div style="height: 20px;">this makes it 100% width in IE.  why?</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can change the "display" value of that div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that may work for you.  It's a little hacky, but if you're trying to find a good width for some text, this is the only way besides javascript that I know of.  We're basically forcing the width by not allowing the line to break.  You can put in `<br/>`s if you need line breaks.

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:50px;left:50px;background:green;width:0px">
 <div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div style="height:50px; white-space:nowrap">This is normally sized in IE6</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

On second thought, don't check out the link.  It's old and doesn't work as advertised.

Old answer:

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/216

I believe that non-absolutely positioned DIVs automatically expand to fill their container horizontally.  Since you haven't specified any container size for this div, it expands to fill the whole page.

I find it odd that Firefox doesn't expand the div... I'm not sure which of them actually has it "right".

Comment: Thank you!  Unfortunately I don't have access to the stylesheet.  This solution seems a bit hackish, too.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, I would say it's something to do with the hasLayout bug in IE6.  My suggestions:
1.  Give the containing div (the one with the absolute positioning) a set width.
2.  Post an example of what you are trying to achieve. We might be able to suggest a more all-browser friendly way of doing what you want.